# Is SQL Server AlwaysOn in VM cluster not needed?

Tags: virtualization, high-availability

We have many SQL Server instances virtualized in Hyper-V and participating in AlwaysOn group. 
I don't know particular reasons behind decisions that led to this setup.

This week I interviewed 15 administrators to our new vacancy. Majority of them had over 15 years of experience. 
When I asked "What tools do you use to make database highly available in virtualized environment?", all of them proposed VM cluster internal mechanics.

Is AlwaysOn really an overkill in our scenario?

Comment: It depends really. What do you use the AlwaysOn Clusters for? How are they configured, how are the resources behind them configured? What is your licensing like? In our shop we have a discount with M$ but we only receive enterprise licenses. As such it doesn't matter if our secondary needs enterprise so we use AlwaysOn. There are so many factors to consider, ask the person who set it up.

Comment: `all of them proposed VM cluster internal mechanics` - I would have asked them what they mean by that. What exactly is `VM cluster internal mechanics`? - `Is AlwaysOn really an overkill in our scenario?` - Without telling us what your scenario is there's no way for us to answer that.